# Transparency issue with png images

Tags: php, gd, alpha-transparency

I 've got this image:
[image: original image with white background]

i use php5 and gd2 library to achieve a transparent background, but the result is not what i have expected(you need a dark background to see the difference):[image: transparent background]

and here is my code:

```
$size = getimagesize($img_url);
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img_url);
$im_tc = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0],$size[1]);
imagecopyresampled($im_tc,$img,0,0,0,0,$size[0],$size[1],$size[0],$size[1]);
imagedestroy($img);
$white  = imagecolorallocatealpha($im_tc, 255, 255, 255,127);
imagecolortransparent($im_tc, $white);
imagepng($im_tc,'image.png');
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Try with replacing the white background color with transparency. Maybe via some fill method to have it continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original image doesn't have a transparent background, but you're trying to create one by changing all pure-white pixels to transparent. As the text has a shadow/glow around it, those pixels aren't quite white, and won't become transparent. You have a couple options here:

- Use an image editor (GIMP, Photoshop, etc.) and their fine-grained selection tools to perform a smart selection of the "background", then remove that. Photoshop, at least, has extremely useful options available on its magic wand tool to choose threshold, feathering, and more.
- Pick more colours to make "transparent." Instead of just white, choose all of the shades of gray, minus the exact colour that ".gr" is set in. This should make all of the shadowed parts of the image transparent as well, although the edges may be less than perfect (i.e.: not feathered, slightly jagged.)

Comment: The problem isn't PHP - the problem is that your original image has a solid background and so it is impossible - Photoshop or GIMP will allow you to try to cut out the image, but it won't be as good as if you have the original layered image